# How to increase progressBar when i running havey query in sql server or oracle?

Tags: c#

i have query that thakes some time until i see the result.

how i can increase progressBar until i get the result ?

(working in C#)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any indication of when it's going to complete, e.g. getting "results so far"? If not, you want to use a [`ProgressBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx) with the [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx) set to [`ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle.aspx) - that will automatically animate, and you just need to stop it afterwards. Note that you'll need to enable visual styles.

Obviously you should perform the query in a background thread (e.g. via [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)) to avoid blocking the UI thread.

If your overall query actually consists of multiple steps, you could make your progress bar more useful by indicating how far it's really gone... but I quite understand that often this isn't the case.

Here's an example of using the marquee style:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Button start = new Button {
            Text = "Start",
            Location = new Point(10, 30)
        };
        Button stop = new Button {
            Text = "Stop",
            Location = new Point(10, 60)
        };

        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar {
            Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee,
            Location = new Point(10, 90),
            MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 20,
            Visible = false
        };
        Form form = new Form {
            Size = new Size(100, 200),
            Controls = { start, stop, bar }
        };
        start.Click += (s, a) => bar.Visible = true;
        stop.Click += (s, a) => bar.Visible = false;
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Serhio: Were you asking or stating? Yes, it will work on .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a thread or, if the problem is that you get a lot of data, use a DataReader and update your progressBar while reading.